# Is there a CKEditor change event that covers toolbar usage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Is there a CKEditor event that I can hook up to that fires whenever the content changes? Ideally I'm looking for an event that fires when anything at all changes, so for example it could be the user typed something into the editor, or a toolbar item was used (e.g. changed the font color).

Currently I'm just hooking up to the `key` event which unsurprisingly only fires when a key is pressed, and not when for example the font color is changed via the toolbar.

```
CKEDITOR.instances['myEditor'].on('key', function () {
    console.log("changed");
});
```

I've also tried using jQuery to delegate a click event on the CKEditor's parent like below. This partly works, for example it fires if you click the Bolt/Italic buttons, but not if you change the font color:

```
$(document).on('click', '#myEditor_DISPLAY', function(){
   console.log("changed");
});
```

I've looked at the [documentation here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html) but haven't found anything. If there's only an event for the toolbar usage then I could make do with that because I can just hookup to both that and the `key` event.